# C#.Net Panel Control and MDI Child forms - issue

Tags: c#, winforms, mdichild

Hi i am stuck in MDIform with panel control.

I have one panel control Docked (fill) to parent MDI form. When i try opening new child form with menu click event the child form doesn't show up in MDI container.

After debugging few times, i set the visible property of panel control to false, the child form shows up now.

what is causing this? is there any way that i can leave panel control as docked (fill) inside MDI container form and show the child form on top of that panel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MDI child windows are always shown as a child of the MDI client area.  The dark gray window in an MDI parent.  You cannot cover this up with a docked panel, the child windows will show *behind* the panel.  Obviously not visible.  You *must* leave room for the client area, a hard requirement.

Answer (score 1):

After the call to the `Show` method for the MDI child form, add the `childForm.BringToFront()` statement. The child form will show in front of the parent form controls.

Answer (score 0):

It might be, that the panel control is shown in front of the MDI child. Try to move the MDI child to the foreground or the panel to the background.

Comment: i suppose that was "in front of MDI child". yes, i resized the panel to half of the container form, child form shows up now. but what is the method to bring form to foreground ? couldn't figure out that.