# panels and child forms in winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, parent-child

i added a panel in my parent winform. the parent form is maximized on the full window when it opens. also, the height of the panel is also of same size as of the parent form i.e. it comes on the full maximized window.  now when i open a child form by clicking on a menustrip item on the parent form , then the child form appears hidden behind the panel, that is, it isn't visible. how to bring it above the panel?

Comment: yes , parent form is mdiParent

Comment: possible duplicate of [C#.Net Panel Control and MDI Child forms - issue.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120568/c-net-panel-control-and-mdi-child-forms-issue)

Answer (score 2):

The forms by default can be childs ONLY of MDI parent form.
If you want set the panel as parent of form, you need use the [SetParent](http://pinvoke.net/search.aspx?search=setparent&namespace=%5BAll%5D) Win32API function.

```
public partial class MDIParentForm: Form
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

    public MDIParentForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void AddChildWindowMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var child = new MDIChildForm();
        child.Show();
        SetParent(child.Handle, BackgroundPanel.Handle);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not possible for MDI child windows.

Comment: i just want that the Parent Form is divided in two halves. One half would contain the treeview of links to child forms and the other half would display the child forms when a link on the tree view would be clicked. how do i do this? please help with code

Comment: for dividing the Parent Form in two halves, I used a Panel, could anything else be used?

Comment: And why don't you use UserControl instead of Form?